# First Robotics Competition, PyNetworkTables nt.thread died

Tags: python

We're using a Raspberry Pi as a Co-Processor, code written in Python, transmitted over to the Robot(code in Java) over pyNetworkTables. The thing is, this error did not occur until the first match on the field. It worked during practice. It also worked after the bridge was imaged.

```
DEBUG:nt:client connected
DEBUG:nt:NetworkConnection stopping (<ntcore.network_connection.NetworkConnection object at 0x712411b0>)
ERROR:nt:Unhandled exception during handshake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ntcore/network_connection.py", line 240, in _readThreadMain
    handshake_success = self.m_handshake(self, _getMessage, self._sendMessages)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ntcore/dispatcher.py", line 488, in _clientHandshake
    msg = get_msg()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ntcore/network_connection.py", line 228, in _getMessage
    return Message.read(self.m_stream, decoder, self.m_get_entry_type)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ntcore/message.py", line 123, in read
    value = codec.read_value(value_type, rstream)
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ntcore/wire.py", line 126, in read_value
    return Value.makeStringArray([self.read_string(rstream) for _ in range(alen)])
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ntcore/wire.py", line 126, in <listcomp>
    return Value.makeStringArray([self.read_string(rstream) for _ in range(alen)])
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ntcore/wire.py", line 198, in read_string_v3
    return rstream.read(slen).decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 47: invalid continuation byte
INFO:nt:DISCONNECTED 10.0.66.2 port 1735 (Robot)
DEBUG:nt:write thread died (<ntcore.network_connection.NetworkConnection object at 0x70088430>)
```

Comment: The problem is the Global-Interpreter-Lock from the python interpreter for handling threads. The workaround is to use another python implemention like Jython or to port the complete code to a mature language like C++. The good news is, that the problem has nothing to do with artificial intelligence nor robotics, it is a simple coding problem which is caused by operating system, computerlanguage and malfunction github-repositories. Its good to know that your team is using python so your question helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely is a unicode bug in the library that you're referring to. We're tracking the bug at https://github.com/robotpy/pynetworktables/issues/42

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library